# mod_rewrite with subdomains not properly catching pattern

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a wild card virtual host which I match with the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.([\d]+)\.mydomain\.com [NC]
```

This rule works:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$       /index.php?customer=%1&cluster=%2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

However if I try to complicate the pattern at all:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/?$ /index.php?customer=%1&cluster=%2&load=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It doesn't catch it. What am I missing?

With the rules above:
http://dev.0.mydomain.com:8080/ works with the first rule
http://dev.0.mydomain.com:8080/x/ fails on the second rule (i.e. modified first rule, there's only one rule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second rule doesn't include the leading slash. Assuming your rules are in vhost context, that part is needed. Specifically, `^([\w\-]+)` doesn't match `/anything`. This would: `^/([\w\-]+)`.

Comment: Oh wow, you were correct! I didn't consider the ^/ because in the old code pre-subdomain we didn't have a / there and it works perfectly fine. Also it wasn't in a vhost context in the old code either. How confusing! Thank you!

Comment: Also, what is ^/([\w\-]+) supposed it match? \w inside a character class is just a literal w. Why not just type that as w?

Comment: It's not a literal w, it matches A-Z, a-z, 0-9.

Comment: Happy days. This page explains these context issues nicely. http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteContext Don't forget the tick :)